# Return Pandas multiindex as list of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

It is possible to create a Multiindex from a list of tuples. I wonder how to do the reverse? Consider the follwing multi-index:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['N', 'R'], ['N', 'R', 'S'], ['N', 'R', 'S'], ['N', 'R', 'S'], ['N', 'R', 'S'], ['N', 'R', 'S'], ['R', 'S'], ['N', 'R', 'S']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
           names=['AMP', 'CZ', 'FOX', 'CRO', 'MER', 'GM', 'CIP', 'SXT'])
```

I want to return a list of tuples that I would use to make a selection with `DataFrame.loc[]` e.g. `[('S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S, 'S'), ...]`

Something I would expect `df.index.as_tuples()` to do, which unfortunately does not exist.

Comment: `idx.values` if `idx` is your MultiIndex?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Either `df.index.tolist()` or `df.index.values` will do.

---

From pandas >= 0.24, you can also use `df.index.to_numpy()`.

Comment: Why is this method called `tolist` instead of `to_list`?

Comment: @Sören I wish I knew. All I can tell you is that it's (almost) a NumPy function, so the conventions used may differ from pandas' naming.

Answer (score 5):

In pandas `0.24+` is possible use [`MultiIndex.to_flat_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html):

```
print (df.index.to_flat_index())
```

**Sample**:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)

print (s.index.to_flat_index())
Index([('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'),
       ('foo', 'one'), ('foo', 'two'), ('qux', 'one'), ('qux', 'two')],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by calling the method `to_native_types()`

```
df.index.to_native_types()
> array([('N', 'N', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'N', 'S', 'N'),
   ('R', 'S', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'S'),
   ('R', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'S'),
   ('R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'S'),
   ('R', 'S', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'),
   ('R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'),
   ('R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'S'),
   ('R', 'S', 'R', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'),
   ...], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Though this has substantial overhead. A `MultiIndex` is an array of tuples: `type(df.index[0])` returns `tuple` so if you want the tuples you can just call `df.index.values`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer thought. It might not be the best one, but it should not be downvoted.

Comment: Not sure why. Wasn't me, although I can see it's a few characters more typing than it needs to be ;-)

Comment: I agree with you, I also didn't downvote and I actually learned about a new method from this :D, though I'm still clueless as to why it exists.The documentation `slice and dice then format` provides little guidance...